# Xcode 9.4.1 not Responding

Tags: xcode

macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6 and Xcode 9.4.1. I try multiple to open Xcode but every time it show not responding and crash. I remove my xcode and again install xcode 9.4.1. but not responding.

[image]

Comment: Restart your PC and try again. If again not responding then wait until responding.

Comment: are you running out of memory?

Comment: Don't open any exsisting project try to open only x-code and create a new project and check ... Is that working ? then you can find the problem .